# Metro UI - create live tiles inside a page

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, microsoft-metro

Is there a way of creating live tiles in a page of Metro App? I want to simulate the tiles of the application inside a page. The tiles can flip to show more data, probably images too.

Edit: Ok, I am already aware that there is nothing done by default. Has anyone done this by himself trying to emulate the actual tiles?

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in functionality to do this, but with WPF it's very very easy to create a grid of icons. Just make your icons 62x62 (the same size as a Live Tile).

Comment: Creating grid seems easy. I was wondering if we have something out of the box for flipping and showing more data

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Windows Animation library - it might simplify your task:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371981(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't think this will help. I need a library to show those animations in metro UI app.

Comment: @kmwoley did you by any change figure anything out regarding this subject. I've been trying for a while too but can't seem to find anything of use?